# floating action button disappearing when dragged to the bottom of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

floating action button on drag disappears. I have a list view on top of it I am adding floating action button on drag to end of the screen it disappears

```
Widget getInitialWidget() {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: Stack(children: [
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildSearchBox(),
              fleetManagerListView(mResponse)
            ],
          ),

          Positioned(
            left : position.dx,
            top  : position.dy ,
            child: Draggable(
              onDragEnd: (details){
                setState(() {
                  position = details.offset;
                  print("position of the floating action button is::");
                  print(position.dx);
                  print(position.dy);
                });
              },
              childWhenDragging: Container(),
              feedback: Visibility(
                visible: userRoleId == 8 ? false : true,
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10),
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: _onFloatingActionButton,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf9b937))),
              ),
child:  Visibility(
  visible: userRoleId == 8 ? false : true,
  child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _onFloatingActionButton,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf9b937))),
),
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
```

drag is working fine but it disappears when I drag to the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

As I see here, your `ListView` is being painted after the `FloatingActionButton`, that means it's on top of the button. When you drag the button to the bottom of the screen, it's being painted underneath the `ListView`, which causing it to disappear.

By placing the `ListView` before the `FloatingActionButton` in the `Stack` widget's children list, the `FloatingActionButton` is painted on top of the `ListView`. So, I though using this way, it will prevent the button to disappear.

Look what I create here;

```
Widget getInitialWidget() {
 return Scaffold(
   key: _scaffoldKey,
   body: Stack(
     children: [
       Positioned(
         left: position.dx,
         top: position.dy,
         child: Draggable(
           onDragEnd: (details) {
             setState(() {
               position = details.offset;
               print("position of the floating action button is::");
               print(position.dx);
               print(position.dy);
             });
           },
           childWhenDragging: Container(),
           feedback: Visibility(
             visible: userRoleId == 8 ? false : true,
             child: Container(
               margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10),
               child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: _onFloatingActionButton,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf9b937),
               ),
             ),
           ),
           child: Visibility(
             visible: userRoleId == 8 ? false : true,
             child: Container(
               margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10),
               child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: _onFloatingActionButton,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf9b937),
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
       Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           _buildSearchBox(),
           fleetManagerListView(mResponse),
         ],
       ),
     ],
   ),
 );
}
```

See in the code that `Positioned` widget (which contains the `FloatingActionButton`) is placed before the `Column` widget (which contains the `ListView`). This way, the button is painted on top of the list, and remain visible when you drag it to the bottom of the screen.